# IPtables blocking SSH, even after its been implicitly enabled?

Tags: ssh, firewall, iptables

Im having trouble with the following iptables entries. I want to stop the server from communicating with the outside world except for ssh, but when I enter the fourth command (iptables -P OUTPUT DROP) I lose my SSH connection, even though ive left it open. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED --dport ssh -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try instead, in line 2:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED --sport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

Assuming that when you say "stop the server from communicating with the outside world except for ssh", you mean "stop the world from communicating with the server except via ssh", then the outbound packet comes **from** the ssh server so has `--sport 22`, not dport.

If you really do mean that you should only be able to talk **from** the server **to** the world via ssh, then line 1 should have the `--sport` instead, as the INPUT packets are those coming from an ssh server.

If you want ssh to work in both directions, you'll need more complex rules.  If you want to allow **new** ssh connections, not just the one that's open when you put the ruleset in place, you'll need more complex rules.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the `iptables` rules are on your server, and your question means you only want to allow SSH connections into that server. Let's analyze your rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

This rule means: only TCP connections *already* in "ESTABLISHED" state can connect to the SSH port. This effectively blocks all connection attempts to SSH, because when someone (you) want to connect to the SSH port, the state is still "NEW" instead of "ESTABLISHED"

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

This rule means: only allow access ***from*** the server ***to*** an SSH port, and only allow "ESTABLISHED" TCP connections. So, that's a type: `--dport` should be `--sport`

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

If your server is ***not*** functioning as a router, you **don't** need a `FORWARD` rule.

```
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

The basic and recommended 'hardening', dropping all traffic not explicitly allowed.

---

#### The correct rules

So, you must change your rules into the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED --sport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT  DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

1. Allow all attempts to connect to the SSH port
2. Allow all replies (TCP state ==
   ESTABLISHED) from the SSH port
3. Drop all other connection
   attempts
4. Drop all other traffic coming
   out of the server

**Important Notes:**

1. Usually you will *want* to allow ICMP coming in and out of your server
2. Usually the `OUTPUT` chain has a default policy of `ACCEPT` instead of `DROP`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Allow SSH on certain ephemeral ports only

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 513:65535 --dport 22  -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 --dport 513:65535  -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 513:65535 --dport 22  -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 --dport 513:65535  -j ACCEPT`

Make sure nothing enters or leaves this box

`iptables -A INPUT -j DROP`

`iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP`

Comment: Thats great!!!   Just wondering if anyone can tell me why ctstate RELATED, ESTABLISHED doesnt/didnt work for me?

Comment: No problem. I was going to point out the --sport and --dport typo but thought you'd prefer something a bit safer if you're completely locking your box down. Sometimes these 'extras' like RELATED and ESTABLISHED need other iptables modules loaded so maybe they're not loaded into memory so I left them out.

Comment: Ugh... someone referred to this as an example of stateless firewall.  Unfortunately the ranges are misleadingly wrong.  That is not the "ephemeral" port range.  E.g. CUPS listens on port 631 on any Linux desktop, so you're letting that through.  The low ports are really 1-1024.  Some old software connects from port >512 (or possibly 600), in order to prove itself as root - like NFS does; it's called `rresvport()` - this should generally be considered obsolete.

Comment: Stateless firewalls work better if you just block on incoming SYN packets (while allowing `SYN|ACK`).

Comment: @sourcejedi If by 'low ports' you mean 'privileged ports' then you're actually off by one: >= 1024 you do not have to have root (or capabilities) privileges. 1023 is the highest port that requires root.